# Convection–diffusion equation in dimension $n$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde, linear-pde

I want to solve the following PDE for $c:\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$,

$${\frac {\partial c}{\partial t}}=\frac12\Delta c-{\vec {v}}\cdot \nabla c,$$

where $\vec{v}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that might depend on $x$.

I looked on wikipedia and realised that it is called a convection-diffusion equation. I don't know how to solve it. I'd like to know if it is possible to solve it exactly (and how?), or is it only possible to solve it numerically?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can solve it with numerical schemes, for many numerical schemes discretized on some grid it will become linear. ut what does $\mathbb R^+$ mean?

Comment: Would separation of variables in the form $ c = T(t)X(\mathbf{x}) $ be of any help here?

Answer (score 1):

Fourier transform in $\vec x$. Then, if you use $\hat f(\vec k) = \int f(\vec x) e^{-i \vec k \cdot \vec x} \, d^n x$, you get 
$$\partial_t \hat c(t, \vec k) = -\frac12 k^2 \hat c(t, \vec k) + \vec v \cdot i\vec k \hat c(t, \vec k) = \left(-\frac12 k^2 + \vec v \cdot i\vec k \right) \hat c(t, \vec k).$$

Thus, 
$$\hat c(t, \vec k) = \hat c(0, \vec k) \exp \left(t (-\frac12 k^2 + \vec v \cdot i\vec k) \right).$$

Then you "only" have to inverse-transform this.

Comment: It's stated in the question that "$\vec{v}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ _that might depend on_ $x$". Your FT hasn't taken that into account.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I read "that does not depend on $x$".

Comment: I actually reedited my question 15 min after that I posted it. In my original version, I said 'that does not depend on $x$'. However, I then realized that for my case, it does depend on $x$, hence changed the question. Sorry for md2perpe. Thank you anyway because I didn't know how to solve the case where $\vec{v}$ is constant either.

Comment: In fact, my vector $\vec{v}$ is a linear combination of terms $1/x_i$, say, $v_i=\sum c_{ij}/x_j$. Is there any hope to solve the equation for that case?